# I want to show product price in 1 pack but sale on whole cartoon pack in magento

Tags: php, magento

I'm new to magento platform.

1. I want to show a product and price (1 pack = 10 pecs) like the actual price 384 and the
   special price is 326
2. but a whole cartoon (1 cartoon=8 pack) is like the actual price: 3072 and the special price is 2612

I want know what to do please help.

thanks

Comment: Please show us your relative code, what have you tried thus far... Stackoverflow is to help people, not to make your app for you for free.. please take the tour: http://stackoverflow.com/tour

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do configure the backend like this :

[image: Minimum Qty Allowed in Shopping cart]

Minimum Qty Allowed in Shopping cart = 10

Enable Qty Increments = Yes

Qty Increments = 10

This may be helpful solution for your 1st point.

You do this and test if you try to give any qty other than multiples of 10. It will not be added to cart and shows following error :

[image]

This may be helpful. Kindly try it once.
Thank you